# Get conversation and last message Query

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm tring to get the conversations with the relative last message and order them by time and if is read the message. Let's go to show the my logic.

I created 3 table: inbox_join / inbox_msg / users

On the first table "inbox join" i have the datas about who have a active discussion. In this case we have id_user - "1" and id_user_2 - "4" they have a conversation.

On the inbox_msg table I have the text message, id conversation where the message will shown and other field easy to understand.

Inbox join table

[image]

Inbox_msg table
[image]

Users table

[image]

I made a query that work fine, but the my issue is that i can't have the occured_at on the inbox_msg table. I would like find a better solution for have my desidered result and i can't order how i'm looking for.

This is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
inbox_join.id_conversation
), user_chat.name AS name_conv, user_chat.surname AS surname_conv, user_chat.username as username_conv, user_chat.id as id_chat, image_upload.name_image, (

SELECT DISTINCT (
message
)
FROM inbox_msg
WHERE inbox_join.id_conversation = inbox_msg.id_conversation
ORDER BY occured_at DESC 
LIMIT 1
) AS last_msg, users.name, users.surname
FROM inbox_join

INNER JOIN users ON users.id = inbox_join.id_user
INNER JOIN users AS user_chat ON user_chat.id <> 1 AND (inbox_join.id_user_2 = user_chat.id || inbox_join.id_user = user_chat.id)
INNER JOIN image_upload ON image_upload.id_image = user_chat.profile_image
WHERE inbox_join.id_user = 1
OR inbox_join.id_user_2 = 1
```

Result desidered selecting the conversation about user 1:

```
id_conversation | id_user | name | surname | username | last_msg | occured_at_last_msg | read_msg |

       1           4         E        S         E           Yes            1380724676        0
       4           5         G        E         K           Good           1380724675        0
```

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
SELECT  im.id_conversation,
        im.id_user,
        u.name,
        u.surname,
        u.username,
        im.message AS last_msg,
        im.occured_at AS occured_at_last_msg,
        im.read_msg 
FROM inbox_msg im
JOIN users u
ON u.id_user = im.id_user
JOIN (SELECT id_conversation,
             MAX(occured_at) AS occured_at
      FROM inbox_msg
      GROUP BY id_conversation) im2
ON im2.id_conversation = im.id_conversation
AND im2.occured_at = im.occured_at
ORDER BY im.occured_at DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

I made this query and should work fine, I would like receive comment about this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
            im.id_conversation
            ), users.name, users.surname, users.username, image_upload.name_image, im.message as last_msg, im.occured_at, im.read_msg
            FROM inbox_join
            INNER JOIN (

            SELECT sub . * 
            FROM (

            SELECT DISTINCT (
            id_conversation
            ), id_user, message, occured_at, read_msg
            FROM inbox_msg
            WHERE id_user <> 1
            ORDER BY occured_at DESC
            ) AS sub
            GROUP BY sub.id_user
            ORDER BY sub.occured_at DESC
            ) AS im ON im.id_conversation = im.id_conversation
            INNER JOIN users ON im.id_user = users.id
            INNER JOIN image_upload ON users.profile_image = image_upload.id_image
            WHERE inbox_join.id_user = 1 || inbox_join.id_user_2 = 1
```

Comment: hm it's Kind of a Mess.. Group by clause without column names, Order by clause in subselect give nothing...